# How to read two arguments in text file?

Tags: python

I'm starting to program in python. I have a question about reading two files inside a text file my code.

```py
arq = open("output.txt", "w")
count = 0
file_path = "/homescript/ASN.txt"
with open(file_path) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if 'AS' in line:
            count = count + 1
            print("set policy", line,"then accept",line, file=arq)
print ("\n Display return",count,"lines")
```

my text file contains:

```
AS0000
192.168.0.1/24
192.168.1.0/24
```

I need print ip address after "then accept"

Comment: Can you check the indentation of the code above? The first print only works if line contains "AS", that IP addresses will not reach to that part of code.

Comment: None of the lines in the sample file have `'AS'` in them.

Comment: what is your expected output>

Comment: this case return for me "set policy AS0000 then accept AS0000" i not get ip address, would i have to use a regex to get AS and ip addrres?

Comment: expected output `set policy AS0000 then accept 192.168.0.1/24` ?

Comment: @CamposTI haven't my answer solve your problem

Comment: Yes @AliHasanAhmedKhan thanks I will adapt to my scenario.

Comment: Welcome CamposTI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arq = open("output.txt", "w")
count = 0
file = open("/homescript/ASN.txt", "r")
t = []
for line in file.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    t.append(line)
for i in range(len(t)):
if 'AS' in t[i]:
    count = count + 1
    print("set policy", t[i], "then accept", t[i+1])
    print("set policy", t[i], "then accept", t[i+2])
print("\n Display return", count, "lines")
```

[image: Output]

Comment: my expected output: set policy AS0000 then accept 192.168.0.1/24 and set policy AS0000 then accept 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: I haven't updated the output, but code will work as your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.readlines` method to get the lines in the file, not just try to iterate from the entire file object. If you want a raw dump, use `file.read()`.

```py
arq = open("output.txt", "w")
count = 0
file_path = "/homescript/ASN.txt"
with open(file_path) as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        if 'AS' in line:
            count = count + 1
            print("set policy", line, "then accept",line, file=arq)
print ("\n Display return", count, "lines")
arq.close()
```

Also don't forget to `.close()` the file.

Comment: this case return for me "set policy AS0000 then accept AS0000"  i not get ip address, would i have to use a regex to get AS and ip addrres?

Comment: Try adding a blank line at the end of your file, because the last character usually gets stripped when you read from a file.

Comment: Additionally, when you use `file` it doesn't read it, it returns some data like `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`

Answer (score 0):

## An easy way

```
count = 0
file_path = "/homescript/ASN.txt"

with open(file_path) as file, open("output.txt", "w") as arq:  # you can open several files at once
    lines = file.readlines()  # read all lines into a list
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[i].rstrip() # extract i-th line
        if 'AS' in line:
            count += 1
            ip = lines[i + 1].rstrip()  # ip is in the following line
            print("set policy", line, "then accept", ip, file=arq)
            
print ("\n Display return", count, "lines")
```

As you can see, the code above reads the whole file and iterates over a list. If a line contains 'AS', the next line is extracted as the IP address. This is not the most pythonic solution, but for you, as a beginner, should be good enough.

---

## A more pythonic one

With the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) from python 3 docs you can do it even more easily:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

count = 0
file_path = "/homescript/ASN.txt"

with open(file_path) as file, open("output.txt", "w") as arq:
    for line, next_line in pairwise(file):
        if 'AS' in line:
            count += 1
            ip = next_line.rstrip()
            print("set policy", line, "then accept", ip, file=arq)      
            
print ("\n Display return", count, "lines")
```